# Jquery target content and place inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that uses a basic wysiwyg editor to handle content. The editor is a little to basic to work with custom designs. So my idea was to create some shortcodes to inject html using jquery.

The setup for the html is pretty basic:

```
<p>[images start]</p>
   <img src="some-image.jpg"/>
   <div class="some-content">Content and other tags</div>
<p>[images end]</p>

<p>[images start align="right"]</p>
   <img src="some-image1.jpg"/>
   <img src="some-image2.jpg"/>
<p>[images end]</p>

<p>[images start align="left"]</p>
   <img src="some-image.jpg"/>
   <div class="some-content">Content and other tags</div>
<p>[images end]</p>
```

The `<p>` wraps are made automatically because of the wysiwyg. The "shortcode" is something i made up to start targeting the content with. It's made for the users to have some extra styling options. The current setup works fine when it's not in a loop and there is only one of a kind. But there are more to be targeted and formatted.

```
// Foreach P that contains 'images start' text
$('p:contains("[images start")').each(function(){

  // Get start and end tag
  var start = $(this);
  var end = $(this).nextAll('p:contains("[images end]")');
  
  // Get content between tags
  var content = start.nextUntil(end);
  
  // Create a new div to place content in
  start.after('<div class="images-multiple"></div>');
  
  // Place content
  $('.images-multiple').html(content);
  
  // Just tests to see it target the shortcodes
  start.css('color','green');
  end.css('color','red');

});
```

The general idea is to wrap the content between the shortcodes in a div with a class, and delete the shortcodes from the DOM. Preferable with the align value inserted somewhere to target it with css.

Maybe this is not a good approach, but due to limitations I can only insert javascript/jquery, no server side support.

Comment: `$('.images-multiple')` selects _all_ the elements of that class currently existing in the document, so you'd be setting the HTML for all of them each time there. Leave that line out, and try something like `start.after('<div class="images-multiple">' + content + '</div>');` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` in your `each` loop to differentiate `.images-multiple` elements.

To set text alignment use `element.text().includes()`.

```js
// Foreach P that contains 'images start' text
$('p:contains("[images start")').each( function(index) {
  const content = $(this).nextUntil($(this).nextAll('p:contains("[images end]")'))
  
  if ($(this).text().includes('align="right"')) {
    $(this).before('<div class="images-multiple" data-index="' + index + '" style="text-align: right;"></div>');
  } else if ($(this).text().includes('align="center"')) {
    $(this).before('<div class="images-multiple" data-index="' + index + '" style="text-align: center;"></div>');
  } else {
    $(this).before('<div class="images-multiple" data-index="' + index + '" style="text-align: left;"></div>');
  }
  
  $(content).appendTo( $('.images-multiple[data-index="' + index + '"]') )
  
  $(this).next('p:contains("[images end]")').remove()
  $(this).remove()
})
```

```css
.images-multiple {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>[images start]</p>
   <img src="some-image.jpg"/>
   <div class="some-content">Content and other tags</div>
<p>[images end]</p>

<p>[images start align="right"]</p>
   <img src="some-image1.jpg"/>
   <img src="some-image2.jpg"/>
<p>[images end]</p>

<p>[images start align="center"]</p>
   <img src="some-image.jpg"/>
   <div class="some-content">Content and other tags</div>
<p>[images end]</p>
```

This will output the following structure:

[image]

Comment: I was messing with the index but couldn't get it to work, thank you for this solution. It's also much cleaner than what I was doing. It works like a charm!